# Obtain final price(s) of item(s) after promotion rules applied?

Tags: price, special-price

How can I obtain the actual final cost of items?

Let's say a customer's out-of-pocket payment for an order is

$1000
and tax is $100
and shipping is $50

So subtracting, all his items AFTER discounts and promo rules (whether it's shopping cart rules or catalog rules) applied would be $850.
Out of the $850, he may have varying items with varying discounts applied and prices (e.g. $250 + $100 + $300 + $200).

**The values $250, $100, $300, $200 are is what I want.**.

How do I obtain them?

Comment: Are working with a quote item or an order item?

Comment: Im using an order

Answer (score 1):

`$product->getFinalPrice()` should give you the price after discount for each item.

Comment: Does it work for shopping cart discounts as well as for catalog discounts?

I tried this, but it said the price was $0.00, which was not correct. This is after a 99% shoppingcart discount, but the total was over $1000, so at least one product's final price should have been non-$0.00.

Comment: do you have cart price rule or catalog price rule applied?

Comment: This is after a 99% shoppingcart discount, but the total was over $1000, so at least one product's final price should have been non-$0.00.

Comment: Can you upload screenshot of your cart page plez.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `sales_flat_order_item` table - this has the details on all ordered items. In your case to access the individual line items something like this would be a starting point:

```
foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
    $item->getBaseRowTotal();
    //or just the discount amount
    $item->getBaseDiscountAmount();
}
```